# Need advice on storing time series data in aligned 10 minute batches per channel

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have time series data in Kafka. The schema is quite simple - the key is the channel name, and the values are Long/Double tuples of the timestamp and the value (in reality it's a custom Avro object but it boils down to this). They always come in correct chronological order.

The wanted end result is data packaged in 10 minute batches, aligned at 10 minutes (i.e., 00:00 < t <= 00:10, 00:10 < t <= 00:20, ..., 23: 50 < t <= 00:00). Each package is to contain only data of one channel.

My idea is to have two Spark Streaming jobs. The first one takes the data from the Kafka topics and dumps it to a table in a Cassandra database where the key is the timestamp and the channel name, and every time such an RDD hits a 10 minute boundary, this boundary is posted to another topic, alongside the channel whose boundary is hit.
The second job listens to this "boundary topic", and for every received 10 minute boundary, the data is pulled from Cassandra, some calculations like min, max, mean, stddev are done and the data and these results are packaged to a defined output directory. That way, each directory contains the data from one channel and one 10 minute window.

However, this looks a bit clunky and like a lot of extra work to me. Is this a feasible solution or are there any other more efficient tricks to it, like some custom windowing of the Kafka data?

Comment: If you're doing stream processing, I think it's better not to use in disk databases like Cassandra. If you have to use a database, In-memory databases like Redis in a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your intuition that this solution is clunky. How about simply using the time windowing functionality built into the Streams DSL?

http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing

The most natural output would be a new topic containing the windowed aggregations, but if you really need it written to a directory that should be possible with Kafka Connect.

Comment: Because the time window functionality depends on arrival of the elements in the stream. However I need event time, my data is timestamped and I need to process 10 minute segments based on these timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Flink Stream Processing, not Spark-streaming but I guess the programming concept of both of them is alike. So supposing data are ordered chronologically and you want to aggregate data for every 10 minutes and do some processing on aggregated data, I think the best approach is to use the *Streaming Window Functions*. I suggest to define a function to map every incoming data's timestamp to the last 10 minutes:

```
12:10:24 ----> 12:10:00
12:10:30 ----> 12:10:00
12:25:24 ----> 12:20:00
```

So you can create a keyed stream object like:

```
StreamObject<Long, Tuple<data>>
```

That the Long field is the mapped timestamp of every message. Then you can apply a window. You should search what kind of window is more appropriate for your case.

**Point:** Setting a key for the data stream will cause the window function to consider a logical window for every key.

- In the most simple case, you should define a time window of *10* minutes and aggregate all data incoming on that period of time.
- The other approach, if you know the rate of generating of data and how many messages will be generated in a period of 10 minutes, is to use *Count window*. For example, a window with the count of 20 will listen to the stream and aggregate all the messages with the same key in a logical window and apply the window function just when the number of messages in the window reaches 20.

After messages aggregated in a window as desired, you could apply your processing logic using a reduce function or some action like that.